# Maven compilation error "package io.restassured.specification does not exist"

Tags: java, maven, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I have imported jar files from "https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Downloads", the first 6. 
And, I have already imported static class "import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*" but still get this compile error. 
Beside the above error I also get this error "package io.restassured does not exist".

Also my Maven dependency is as follows:

```
<!-- rest assured library for API-level testing -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-path -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- to validate that a JSON response conforms to a Json Schema -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The code snippet:

```
public static List<String> passParams(List<String> list){
    RestAssured.baseURI = freightRootURL;
    RequestSpecification requestSpecification = given();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() ; i ++ ) {
        requestSpecification = requestSpecification.queryParam(freightParams.get(i), list.get(i));
    }
    String result = requestSpecification.when().get().then().assertThat().statusCode(200).extract().response().asString();

    JsonPath js = new JsonPath(result);
    String offers = js.getString("offers.key");

    return Arrays.asList(offers.split(","));
```

Comment: What's your build status ?

Comment: Build failure, compilation error

Comment: Do you write this test in the 'Test' folder (in src folder) in the maven project structure?

Comment: What do you mean by `I have imported jar files from "https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Downloads",` I don't understand that? Have you downloaded them?

Comment: I first downloaded them and import them manually in Intellij.

Comment: I am using Cucumber, so steps are in test folder but this specific file is not.

Answer (score 0):

adding the dependencies solved this issue on my end

used a stsarter projec from https://code.quarkus.io/ and added the dependencies afterwards